# How to set parity/stop bits on Keyspan (or other) usb-to-serial / RS232 converter? (stty doesn't work)

Tags: drivers, firmware, serial-port

I have two different usb-to-serial adapters, a Keyspan USA-19HS and a Plugable usb serial converter. Plugging either in to my Ubuntu 20.10 Lenovo X1 laptop results in a /dev/ttyUSB0 being created that I can open and read from.

However, no combination of either flags in [pyserial](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/) when reading the serial port via python, or parenb or cstopb arguments to `stty` when reading the port via `hd` seem to change the data I can read from the serial port. It's as if the driver is ignoring the parity/stop-bit parameters. I'm trying to read data from a serial source that uses even parity and 1 stop bit.

Somewhat suspiciously, in my console log, it looks like the keyspan driver isn't loading any firmware.  Here's what I see in the console log after doing a `dmesg -n 8` and plugging in the Keyspan converter:

```
Jan 11 16:40:20 X1-6th kernel: [ 8099.025705] usbcore: registered new interface driver keyspan
Jan 11 16:40:20 X1-6th kernel: [ 8099.025717] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for Keyspan - (without firmware)
Jan 11 16:40:20 X1-6th kernel: [ 8099.025724] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for Keyspan 1 port adapter
Jan 11 16:40:20 X1-6th kernel: [ 8099.025730] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for Keyspan 2 port adapter
Jan 11 16:40:20 X1-6th kernel: [ 8099.025736] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for Keyspan 4 port adapter
Jan 11 16:40:26 X1-6th kernel: [ 8105.207664] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Jan 11 16:40:26 X1-6th kernel: [ 8105.376377] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=06cd, idProduct=0121, bcdDevice= 1.00
Jan 11 16:40:26 X1-6th kernel: [ 8105.376386] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 11 16:40:26 X1-6th kernel: [ 8105.376390] usb 1-2: Product: Keyspan USA-19H 
Jan 11 16:40:26 X1-6th kernel: [ 8105.376394] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Keyspan, a division of InnoSys Inc.
Jan 11 16:40:26 X1-6th kernel: [ 8105.381746] keyspan 1-2:1.0: Keyspan 1 port adapter converter detected
Jan 11 16:40:26 X1-6th kernel: [ 8105.381952] usb 1-2: Keyspan 1 port adapter converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

And I have various Keyspan firmware, including usa19.fw in /lib/firmware/keyspan, found from http://www.chrisdanielson.com/2012/04/10/linux-firmware-keyspan-usb-to-serial/.

There's some info on linux usb serial support at https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/usb/usb-serial.html, but I didn't see a good solution there.

Has any figured out either how to effectively set partiy/stop bits with a keyspan adapater, or know of a usb-serial adapter that has linux support to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the driver was working fine. The source was using a non-standard baud rate. Pyserial supports custom baud rates, so once I knew what it was using, the data came through ok with Even parity.